# Avoid MouseOver Event in Silverlight on specific control

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a number of ellipse controls that are programmatic added on a page. On these controls I have MouseOver events. But I also have a number of lines running over these controls. They aren't however related as in parent/child or anything.

My problem that I need help with is how to *avoid that the MouseOver event on the lines fires their event and causes the MouseLeave on the ellipse controls*. I don't want anything to happens when one hover over the lines and want the MouseLeave to fire first when one leaves the ellipse (and not when hovering over a line above the ellipse like now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write the below in the MouseOver event of the lines

```
e.Handled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set IsHitTestVisible for your lines to False.